# Add a "select link of an existing content" to a metabox in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a wordpress template and would like to insert a slider on the home page with some call to action . I'm just using the carousel bootstrap and custom post type . In the administrative part of the custom post type I added a Metabox that has the input to insert the link that goes in the button that is displayed in the slide . I would like to include in the Metabox the ability to select from a dropdown list links to existing page or post or cutom post type of the website. Is there a way to do this without having to create a loop that displays pages and posts ? something like the function 
 **wp_dropdown_page** ? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

one good solutions would be to use CMB2 to manage your metaboxes.

https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2 or https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes

with this plugin you can make easy nice metaboxes with autocomplete and so on.